# How to compare 2 object arrays using Assert array Equals in Junit

Tags: assertion

I am new to Java & Junit. I have a problem statement to write test case for testing "findRoleWithMaxPrivilege" method in which role array needs to be passed. Basically this method needs to return the role array where the role has maximum privileges. Please find the below method & the corresponding test case details. But this test scenarios is returning error.

```
public class Privilege {
    String name;
public class Role extends RoleBO{
    private String name;
    private Privilege[] privilege;
    public Role(String name, Privilege[] privilege) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.privilege = privilege;
    }
public class RoleBO {
public RoleBO(){}
public Role[] findRoleWithMaxPrivilege(Role[] role)
{
    int count,i;
    int c=0;
    this.sortRoleByName(role);
    count = this.CountMaxNoOfPrivilege(role);
    Integer no = this.countNoofMaxPrivilege(role,count);
    Role[] rol = new Role[no];
    for( i = 0;i < role.length;i++)
        if(role[i].getPrivilege().length == count)
            rol[c++] = role[i];
    return rol;
}
```

*

```
public class RoleJUnit {
    RoleBO role;
    @Before
    public void objectCeration() {
         role = new RoleBO();
    }
    @Test
    public void testFindRoleWithMaxPrivilege() {
        Role[] input = new Role[3];
        Privilege[] privil = new Privilege[5];
        privil[0] = new Privilege("A");
        privil[1] = new Privilege("SA");
        privil[2] = new Privilege("M");
        privil[3] = new Privilege("SM");
        privil[4] = new Privilege("PA");
        input[0] = new Role("Pavi",privil);

    Privilege[] privil2 = new Privilege[3];
    privil2[0] = new Privilege("A");
    privil2[1] = new Privilege("SA");
    privil2[2] = new Privilege("M");
    input[1] = new Role("Heidi",privil2);

    Privilege[] privil3 = new Privilege[2];
    privil3[0] = new Privilege("A");
    privil3[1] = new Privilege("SA");
    input[2] = new Role("Dora",privil3);

    Role[] actual = role.findRoleWithMaxPrivilege(input);

    Role[] expected = new Role[1];
            Privilege[] Privilexpected = new Privilege[5];
            Privilexpected[0] = new Privilege("A");
            Privilexpected[1] = new Privilege("SA");
            Privilexpected[2] = new Privilege("M");
            Privilexpected[3] = new Privilege("SM");
            Privilexpected[4] = new Privilege("PA");
            expected[0] = new Role("Pavi",Privilexpected);
    Assert.assertArrayEquals("Mismatch",expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Hamcrest library to assert the collections. Hamcrest contains built in collection matchers. 
[This](https://www.baeldung.com/java-junit-hamcrest-guide) link might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare and define the "role" like below. Rest of the code everything is good. It's working for me.

```
public class RoleJUnit {
  RoleBO roleBO;
   Role role;
@Before 
    public void objectCeration()
{
    //fill code here.
    roleBO = new RoleBO();
    role = new Role();
}
```